# CakePHP to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

I'm in the process of migrating a cakephp website to WordPress. The cake site has over 200 pages so I'd like to find a way of exporting these pages in csv format or similar from phpmyadmin and importing directly to wp. Has anyone done this before? Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: you want to export data or page's structure (html) to csv?

Comment: i just want to export data from cakePHP to wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content in the Cake is probably in a special database table. You can write a simple PHP script to read this table and then dump this content into the Wordpress database, using a few SQL statements. Easy task.